# Can not organize data in input collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, formtastic

I have `payment_type` model with 3 elements saved. Also I have an `order`, where I want to store `payment_type_id`. I write in order view: 
    `<%= f.input :pay_type_id, :as => :select, collection: PaymentType.names  ...%>`
But `payment_type_id` already saves as 0. As I understand, I'm trying to record `payment_type.name` instead of `payment_type.id`. What do I have to write in `collection:` to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<%= f.select :pay_type_id, PaymentType.all.collect {|x| [x.name, x.id]} %>
```

This will display the name of the pay_type to the user in the dropdown, but submit the id of the pay_type to your form.